# Overlay polygon on top of image in Python

Tags: python, image-processing, overlay

Say I have an image in PIL

```
from PIL import Image
Image.open(path_to_my_image)
```

and two lists of `x` points and `y` points

```
x = ['10', '30', '70']
y = ['15', '45', '90']
```

Is there a way to overlay my polygon **with transparency** on this image?

Also, is PIL a good library for this? Or should I use a different one? (e.g. `scikits.image`, or render in an image with pylab).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PIL is a fine tool for this:

```
import Image
import ImageDraw
img = Image.open(...).convert('RGBA')

x = ['10', '30', '70']
y = ['15', '45', '90']

# convert values to ints
x = map(int, x)
y = map(int, y)

img2 = img.copy()
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img2)
draw.polygon(zip(x,y), fill = "wheat")

img3 = Image.blend(img, img2, 0.5)
img3.save('/tmp/out.png')
```

---

The call signature for `draw.polygon` is:

```
def polygon(self, xy, fill=None, outline=None):
```

so the only options are `fill` and `outline`. I looked at the source code to find this information.

IPython told me:

```
In [38]: draw.polygon?
...
File:       /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/ImageDraw.py
```

which showed me where to look.

---

To draw a semi-transparent polygon on top of `img`, make a copy of the image. One the copy, draw the polygon in full color without alpha. Then use [Image.blend](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm) to combine the original image with the copy with a set level of `alpha`. For each pixel:

```
out = image1 * (1.0 - alpha) + image2 * alpha
```

Comment: Fantastic! Is there a way to have a transparent fill? Also, where can I look up the options for `draw.polygon`? (I checked here: http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/imagedraw.htm but I could not find a list of accepted options)

Comment: `polygon` complains with `Integer is required` when I pass it the `fill` argument.

Comment: Add `.convert('RGBA')` to the `img = Image.open(...)` statement.

Comment: Great! The `convert` statement fixed the error, but I still don't see any transparency.. Hmm.. and I tried with different values for the last scalar of the vector.

Comment: @user273158 you need to draw the polygon into a different image then use `blend` or `composite` to put it into the original. PIL wasn't really designed to do transparency in an intuitive manner.

Answer (score 9):

To do that you can use [Shapely](https://pypi.org/project/Shapely/) and [OpenCV](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/) like this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

x = [10, 30, 70]
y = [15, 45, 90]
alpha = 0.5 # that's your transparency factor
path = 'path_to_image.jpg'

polygon = Polygon([(x[0], y[0]), (x[1], y[1]), (x[2], y[2]), (x[0], y[2])])
int_coords = lambda x: np.array(x).round().astype(np.int32)
exterior = [int_coords(polygon.exterior.coords)]

image = cv2.imread(path)
overlay = image.copy()
cv2.fillPoly(overlay, exterior, color=(255, 255, 0))
cv2.addWeighted(overlay, alpha, image, 1 - alpha, 0, image)
cv2.imshow("Polygon", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: `cv2.fillPoly` may have issues with convex polygons. These are handled well by PIL.